# Would the .NET JIT compiler optimize out a method call?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, clr

The stack trace I get back from an ASP.NET application, generated from an ArgumentNullException, gives the impression that an error occurs on the last line of the code below. As far as I can see, that is impossible, but if the JIT optimized out the call to `Bar`, which would result in a different stack trace, it would explain all. I know for sure its not the c# compiler, as the CIL looks like I would expect. Is it possible the JIT compiler removed the call to Bar?

c# 4, .NET 4.0.30319.1, ASP.NET 4.0.30319.1

**EDIT:**
I should have mentioned this is a release configuration, with Optimize code = on, Debug Info = pdb-only.

```
Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value]
CreateHiddenField(HtmlTextWriter tr, String name, String value) in Foo.cs:129
Foo(IHttpContext context, HtmlTextWriter writer) in Foo.cs:106
```

---

```
private static void Foo(IHttpContext context, HtmlTextWriter writer)
{ // line 103
  Bar(writer, AuthorizationServerResponseDetailsHttpRequestParser.RequestSAMLFieldName, context);
  Bar(writer, AuthorizationServerResponseDetailsHttpRequestParser.RequestTargetFieldName, context);
  // line 106 - blank line in source code.
  CreateHiddenField(tr, name, string.Empty); // looks like its here
}

private static void Bar(HtmlTextWriter tr,string name, IHttpContext context)
{ // line 116
   #region Sanitation
   if (tr == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("tr"); }
   if (name == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("name"); }
   if (context == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("context"); }
   #endregion

   CreateHiddenField(tr, name, context.RequestQueryString(name));
}

private static void CreateHiddenField(HtmlTextWriter tr, string name, string value)
{ // line 127
   #region Sanitation
   if (tr == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("tr"); }
   if (name == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("name"); }
   if (value == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("value"); }
   #endregion

   // payload...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? The JIT can inline a method if it fits the requirements - which could cause it to 'disappear' from the stack trace... I think.

Comment: its there, in the first code block. I removed the namespace / file names to make it readable.

Comment: What do you know, I didn't think that was a stack trace since it was so small. My guess is it was inlined, but I don't know if the compiler emits code to keep the 'proper' stack trace or not. Does the stack trace come with any line number or byte offsets?

Comment: `AuthorizationServerResponseDetailsHttpRequestParser` ... nice one :)

Comment: @Joshua updated there with the line numbers from the stack trace, and the code too.

Comment: @Gene thats not even the half of it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx, if the JITter inlines a method call, it will indeed be collapsed in the stack trace. If you don't want it to inline (which is probably not a good idea), you can use

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

on the method. For an exe, you can also use an INI file to tell the JITter to generate tracking information (at the bottom of the linked page), but I'm not sure how that would work for an ASP.NET app.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: perfect. URL confirms what I suspected, but I couldn't find anything like that article when I searched.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen the JIT remove a method call, just inline it.  Often, it will remove unused local variables, but I'm fairly certain the JIT can't staticly analyze all of the side-effects from calling a method, so I don't think it will ever remove a method call.

My guess is that a null value is being passed to a method that is called inside `CreateHiddenField`, which happens to also have a parameter `value`.  Because inlining is enabled in Release modes by default, you can't really trust the stack trace (or the supposed line numbers where the exception happened).  Chances are your problem lies inside `CreateHiddenField` or deeper into the invisible stack. :)

You can disable optimizations to get a better idea of the stack trace.  [MSDN has some instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x.aspx)